# How to extract the year of timestamp field in "where" zone and compare with the current year using postgres 9.6?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hi I'm trying to do this query when the current year and the year of the first published is the same but it does not work. How can I do it?

I want the select of the fields with the year of the first_published field (TimeStamp format) queals to the current year.

```
select distinct name, userid, code, last_updated, first_published 
from users 
where date_part('year', first_published) = date_part('year', current_date) 
  and first_published is not null

select distinct name, userid, code, last_updated, first_published 
from users 
where extract(year from first_published) = date_part(year from current_date) 
  and first_published is not null
```

Error:

```
ERROR:  function date_part(unknown, character varying) does not exist
LINE 7: where date_part('year', first_published) = date_part('year',...
              ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
********** Error **********

ERROR: function date_part(unknown, character varying) does not exist
SQL state: 42883
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Character: 298
```

The image of first_published field

[image: The image of first_published field]

Comment: "*It does not work*" is not a valid Postgres error message. You need to tell us what you expect, what you get and why what you get is not what you want.

Comment: Why does the title says postgresql **9.6** and tag says **9.4**? Which one is it?

Comment: I updated the question with your requirements @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: I updated the tags @MatteoTassinari

Comment: The first is OK, and the second query will work just fine if you use the correct syntax. Change `date_part(year from current_date) ` to `extract(year from current_date)`. The error message suggests that you are not storing your timestamp as `timestamp` but in a `varchar` column. Why are you doing that?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I think, my field is in TIMESTAMP, you can see the updated question, no?

Comment: Apparently it is not, otherwise the query would work see here: http://rextester.com/ZNP84626

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [right syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-datetime.html) of **date_part** function is:

```
date_part('year', first_published)
```

assuming that first_published is a timestamp.

The problem could be the **null value** of this field. In where close you have:

```
where date_part('year', first_published) = date_part('year', current_date) 
  and first_published is not null
```

The date_part function call occure **before** `is not null` evaluation. This cause an exception when value of this field is null.

I think the replacement of the where close like this:

```
   where first_published is not null and 
date_part('year', first_published) = date_part('year', current_date)
```

Can solve this issue.

You could try also:

```
where date_part('year', coalesce(first_published, current_date +370)) = date_part('year', current_date)
```

**Explanation:** The `coalesce` function replace null value by date in the next year and do nothing when first_published is not null.

Comment: "*This cause an exception when value of this field is null*" this is wrong. `date_part()` or `extract()` can absolutely handle null values and will simply return null in that case.

Comment: The `first_published is not null` is also useless.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You're right. Apologize, I answered without testing.

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty clear:

> ERROR: function date_part(unknown, character varying) does not exist

The *second* argument, `first_published`, is a string, not a date -- despite what you say in the text, I don't think the error message misleads.  You need to convert it to a date.

You could try:

```
where date_part('year', first_published::date) = date_part('year', current_date)
```

However, you might need to take the format into account.

Comment: I actualized the question, you can see the image, the definition of first_published field